How to set the width of center region to zero in the dynamic island with swiftui
How can I achieve something like this in the document?

I don't want any center region. I want to make the red rect vertical-align to the leading region, and the green rect right below the trueDepth camera region while in the same HStack group which also contains the red rect.
I didn't see any differences when I tried to set the region priority. Nothing happens and the leading region didn't enlarged.
Any help is appreciated.

You need to edit your question to include all relevant code in the form of a minimal reproducible example in order to make the question on-topic.
